# gridview storing the records but displaying last entered record on each reload of the web page

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my application I first need to have a button on clicking the button user should see a pop up with labels and text boxes and on clicking the add button the data should be added to grid view every thing is done but if for the first time I enter the details of a person and I click on add button then they are added to gridview. Again if I enter details of another person then the details  are added to gridview like this i am able to add the details to gridview but if i am reloading the page in the browser after reloading lastly entered record is getting added but it should not get added just the page should be reloaded and grid should get disappered againg when i run the application those records should be displayed how can i do this

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .Background
        {
            background-color: Black;
            filter: alpha(opacity=90);
            opacity: 0.8;
        }
        .Popup
        {
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
            border-width: 3px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: black;
            padding-top: 10px;
            padding-left: 10px;
            width: 400px;
            height: 350px;
        }
        .lbl
        {
            font-size:16px;
            font-style:italic;
            font-weight:bold;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Fill Form in Popup" />

            <div style="margin-left:10px;margin-top:10px">  
     <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server" CellPadding="2"  
        ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">  
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />  
        <Columns>  
            <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-Width="120px" HeaderText="FirstName" DataField="FirstName" />  
            <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-Width="120px" HeaderText=" MiddleName" DataField="MiddleName" />  
            <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-Width="120px" HeaderText=" LastName" DataField="LastName" />  
            <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-Width="120px" HeaderText="Gender" DataField="Gender" />  
        </Columns>  
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />  
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />  
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />  
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />  
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />  
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />  
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />  
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />  
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />  
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />  
    </asp:GridView>  
    </div>  
<!-- ModalPopupExtender -->
<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="mp1" runat="server" PopupControlID="Panl1" TargetControlID="Button1"
    CancelControlID="Button2" BackgroundCssClass="Background">
</cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:Panel ID="Panl1" runat="server" CssClass="Popup" align="center" style = "display:none">
    <div id="irm1" style=" width: 300px; height: 250px;" runat="server" >
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" CssClass="lbl" Text="First Name"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Font-Size="14px" ></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" CssClass="lbl" Text="Middle Name"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Font-Size="14px" ></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" CssClass="lbl" Text="Last Name"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Font-Size="14px" ></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" CssClass="lbl" Text="Gender"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Font-Size="14px" ></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    <td>
    <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="Button3_Click" />
    </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
        </div>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Close" />
</asp:Panel>
<!-- ModalPopupExtender -->
    </form>
</body>
```

In my code behind-

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (Session["Data"] == null) 
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
            dt.Columns.Add("FirstName");
            dt.Columns.Add("LastName");
            dt.Columns.Add("Qualification");
            dt.Columns.Add("Salary");
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow(); 
            dr[0] = TextBox1.Text;
            dr[1] = TextBox2.Text;
            dr[2] = TextBox3.Text;
            dr[3] = TextBox4.Text;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            GridView1.DataSource = dt; 
            GridView1.DataBind();

            Session["Data"] = dt;            
        }
        else
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = (DataTable)Session["Data"]; 
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow(); 
            dr[0] = TextBox1.Text;
            dr[1] = TextBox2.Text;
            dr[2] = TextBox3.Text;
            dr[3] = TextBox4.Text;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            GridView1.DataSource = dt; 
            GridView1.DataBind();

            Session.Remove("Data");
            Session["Data"] = dt;
        }

        ClearFields();
    }
    protected void ClearFields()
    {
        TextBox1.Text = "";
        TextBox2.Text = "";
        TextBox3.Text = "";
        TextBox4.Text = "";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following method gets called up when the Add button of the modal popup is clicked. The following method simply calls the stored procedure, Replace stored procedure name with your stored  procedure name.

```
protected void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "AddUpdateCustomer";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", TextBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", TextBox2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MiddleName", TextBox3.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", TextBox4.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

**For closing the popup on close button** you need to add some script like below:

Your Close `Button` Replace with this:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Close" OnClientClick = "return Hidepopup()"/>
```

Put this `Script` in your `form`

```
<script type = "text/javascript">    
    function Hidepopup() {
        $find("popup").hide();
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

**Update:** `Form1` should be formatted like below if you want everything in one `form`

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>    
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
     <style type="text/css">    
        .Background {    
            background-color: Black;    
            filter: alpha(opacity=90);    
            opacity: 0.8;    
        }    
        .Popup {    
            background-color: #FFFFFF;    
            border-width: 3px;    
            border-style: solid;    
            border-color: black;    
            padding-top: 10px;    
            padding-left: 10px;    
            width: 400px;    
            height: 350px;    
        }    
        .lbl {    
            font-size:16px;    
            font-style:italic;    
            font-weight:bold;    
        }    
    </style>
</head>
<body>
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">    
</asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Fill Form in Popup" />   

<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="mp1" runat="server" PopupControlID="Panl1" TargetControlID="Button1"    
    CancelControlID="Button2" BackgroundCssClass="Background">    
</cc1:ModalPopupExtender>

    <asp:Panel ID="Panl1" runat="server" CssClass="Popup" align="center" style = "display:none">    

    <div id="irm1" style=" width: 350px; height: 300px;" runat="server" >
        <table>        
            <tr>        
                <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" CssClass="lbl" Text="First Name"></asp:Label> </td>        
                <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Font-Size="14px" ></asp:TextBox> </td>  </tr>

                <tr>        
                <td>        
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" CssClass="lbl" Text="Middle Name"></asp:Label> </td>        
                <td>        
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Font-Size="14px" ></asp:TextBox> </td>  </tr>

                <tr>        
                <td>        
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" CssClass="lbl" Text="Last Name"></asp:Label> </td>        
                <td>        
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Font-Size="14px" ></asp:TextBox> </td>        
                </tr>        
                <tr>        
                <td>        
                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" CssClass="lbl" Text="Gender"></asp:Label> </td>        
                <td>        
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Font-Size="14px" ></asp:TextBox> </td> </tr>    
                <tr>
                <td align="">
                <asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="btn1_Click" /> </td> 
                <td> asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Close" />   </td> 
            </tr>
        </table>
    <br/>    

    </div>      
    </asp:Panel>     
 </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116692/discussion-between-rahul-hendawe-and-kavitha-vemula).

Comment: your requirements are continuously changing @Kavitha :) 
Add Gridview control in your form and bind it on page load or whenever you want after save.

Comment: As your are not storing the data into `database` it gets disappeared after `postback` , you can avoid it for every postback by putting the `page_load`  code inside `if(!ispostback)`. for better result i will suggest you to first store data into `database` and bind that to `GridView` instead of creating datatable and bind it to `GridView` on every `Add Button` Click.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to preserve data even after application stop and restart you have to store data in database/file.

in your code it seem like an you are storing data in datatable only, so when you stop/restart or even when object goes out of scope data going to flush so if you want to preserve it use database to store it.

Comment: ok then delete old comment and have you called gridDataBind(); in form load event?

Comment: when you write code you must have to know about the use of them, you know viewstate its going to destroy when onpageunload. have you seen this post ??http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/75a48f/how-to-use-xml-file-to-store-data-and-retrieve-data-using-as/